# hibernate update for a one to many relationship when associate table gets more rows

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

Entity

```
@Table(name = "SERVICE")
public class Service implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The serviceId. */
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SERVICE_SEQ", sequenceName = "SERVICE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SERVICE_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_ID", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(10)")

    /** The description. */
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)")
    private String description;

     @OneToMany(targetEntity = ServiceAddress.class, mappedBy = "service",
     cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     private Set<ServiceAddress> serviceAddressSet;

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class ServiceAddress implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SERVICE_ADDRESS_SEQ")
    @Column(unique = true, name = "SERVICE_ADDRESS_ID", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(10)")
    private int serviceAddressId;

    /** The service address. */
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(200)" ,nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID",nullable = false)
    private Service service;

    /**
     * Gets services.
     * 
     * @return the services
     */
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    /**
     * Sets services.
     * 
     * @param services
     *            the services to set
     */
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

these are two of my entity classes and I want to delete multiple rows in `ADDRESS` table for particular `serviceId` by using Hibernate. I couldn't use `serviceId` for query because in `ADDRESS` table I mapped it with a service object.

Answer (score 0):

session.beginTransaction();

```
    Service service = session.load(Service.class, 114);

    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Address.class);

    c.add(Restrictions.eq("service", service));

    List<Address> list = c.list();

    for (Address as : list) {

        session.delete(as);

    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Hope this will help !!